# What does battle icons (buffs and debuffs) mean?

Tags: star-wars-galaxy-of-heroes

Is there any detailed description of each icon - buff & debuff - that  can occur in a battle of Galaxy of Heroes ?

For example, I know that a green shield represents additional armor for your character, but some are a bit more complicated to guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could read what every effect does by tapping on it during battle.

Check this article [Positive and Negative Status Effects Explained](http://www.swgohcantina.com/positive-and-negative-status-effects-explained/). Quote from it (in case the link goes down):

**Buffs**:

> - **Critical Chance Up**: This buff increases the Physical and Special Critical Rating by 25%.
> - **Defense Up**: Increases the Armor and Resistance of a Hero by 50%.
> - **Evasion Up**: Adds 10% to the dodge stat which governs the chance of avoiding any physical type damage entirely.
> - **Foresight**: Grants a Hero 100% Evasion chance against one attack and then it expires.
> - **Health Up**: Increases the maximum health of a character based on the percentage gain in the ability it generated from.
> - **Offense Up**: Grants a bonus of 50% to Physical and Special damage stats.
> - **Potency Up**: High tenacity characters tend to resist debuffs often, so this buff increases the chance to apply detrimental or negative effects.
> - **Retribution**: Provides the character Counterattack.
> - **Speed Up**: Grants an ally +25% speed providing faster refilling turn meters for  more actions per battle.
> - **Stealth**: Stealthed characters are not directly targetable unless only stealthed heroes are remaining.
> - **Taunt**: Characters with taunt will force all opponents to target them until the effect expires.

**Negative Effects or Debuffs**

> - **Ability Block**: Prevents a hero from using their special abilities. Carefully time applying this debuff so it’s not wasted if the enemy’s special is on cooldown.
> - **Buff Immunity**: Prevents a hero from receiving positive effects.
> - **Continuous Damage**: This is a Damage over Time (DoT) effect that reduces health at the beginning of the character’s turn.
> - **Defense Down**: Decreases the Armor and Resistance of a Hero by 50%.
> - **Expose**: A character takes damage equal to 20% of their max health the next time damaged.
> - **Healing Immunity**: Heroes effected by this cannot be healed.
> - **Offense Down**: Reduces Physical and Special damage stats by 50%.
> - **Speed Down**: Slows the turn meter down by 25% which reduces the amount of actions a hero can take during battle.
> - **Stun**: Stunned characters will miss their next turn.
> - **Bomb**: The thermal detonator grenade will explode and damage the squad based on the countdown timer of the ability.

Article is somehow obsolete, some fixes/additions from me:

- **Advantage** now only guarantees 100% critical on next attack.
- **Tactical Genius** gives 100% TM after using special ability.

New debuffs were introduced:

- **Shock** prevents healing, TM gain, Buff gain.
- **Daze** prevents TM gain and counterattack.

Ships battles have some additional effects (but they sometimes reuse old icons):

- **Damage immunity** from Mace Window's Endurance.
- **Master Plan** from Admiral Acbar's Home One. Grants 100% TM and cooldown resets if special ability is used.
- **Thrust Reversal** of Millennium Falcon: +4% Evasion per stack, 1 stack lost on taking damage; at end of turn, 1 stack is consumed to gain 100% Turn Meter.
- Debuff **Target Locked**: debuff which does nothing by itself, but some abilities have additional effects if target is locked.

Comment: This answer needs updating, as it's missing a couple of effects (Health over Time and Burning to name a couple).

Answer (score 1):

An up to date list of status effects can be found here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F86_j4IqMQ45HK4a0_3RNYb9mF4Jb0hTmbmMU2RoLEQ/edit#gid=0

The effects missing from the above post:

Buffs:

> - Backup Plan - Unit recovers 10% Health at start of turn, Revives with 80% Maximum Health and 30% Turn Meter. Status Effect cannot be
>   Dispelled.
> - Bonus Protection - Unit is granted X Bonus Protection when applied.
> - Bounty Hunter's Resolve - Status Effect cannot be Dispelled. Unit ignores Taunt. When defeated, revive unit at X% Health (Ability level
>   dependent).
> - Call to Action - Luke ignores Taunts during his turn and has +50% Accuracy, +50% Critical Chance, and +50% Critical Damage. Can't be Dispelled or prevented.
> - Continuous Healing (HoT) - At the start of the units next turn, heal unit for X% amount.
> - Critical Damage Up - Add 50% Damage to Critical Attacks made by this unit.
> - Critical Hit Immunity - This unit cannot be Critically Hit, and will suffer normal damage from attacks.
> - Deadly - Lowered Max HP, Massively Increased Damage. Status Effect cannot be dispelled. NPC Event Status Only.
> - Frenzy - Give this unit 100% Turn Meter when any Ally uses a Special Ability.
> - Master's Training - +25% (doubled on Jedi) Accuracy, Defense, Offense, Potency, and Tenacity. Can't be Dispelled or Prevented.
> - Protection Up - Unit gains X% Protection.
> - Protection Recharge - At the start of unit's turn, gain X Protection.
> - Tenacity Up - Unit gains maximum Tenacity for duration of Status Effect.
> - Secret Intel - +25% Potency and when another ally uses a Special ability they gain Secret Intel for 3 turns, then the cooldown of Illuminated Destiny is reduced by 1 for each ally with Secret Intel.
> - Valor - At end of unit's turn, Endurance gains 20% Turn Meter, and reduces the cooldown of Convergence by 1.

Debuffs:

> - Armor Shred - -50% Defense per stack. Raid Boss: -25% Defense per stack
> - Burning - Deals damage over time and reduces Evasion chance to base 2%
> - Critical Chance Down - reduces chance of scoring a critical hit
> - Deathmark - While active, only units with Deathmark are targetable, and afflicated unit suffers damage equal to 50% of their max health
>   when damaged. - Units with Taunt are still prioritized over units
>   with Deathmark.
> - Evasion Down - Reduces chance to evade an enemies attack
> - Fracture - Unit Speed set to 0, cannot gain Positive Effects, bonus Turn Meter, or bonus Attacks. Raid Boss: -50% Speed (does not stack
>   with Speed Down)
> - Health Down - Max and Current Health total reduced by 20%.
> - Plague: Unit loses 5% Health when inflicted and at the start of their turn, is immune to allied Dispels, and loses all stacks of Plague when healed to full Health
> - Target Lock (Character Battle) - While Imperial Probe Droid is active, enemy units with Target Lock cannot gain buffs and have -25% evasion
> - Tenacity Down - Unit loses all Tenacity for duration of Status Effect. - Note: Unit still has base 15% chance to resist detrimental effect.